# How to get domain wide delegation access for mail ID, in order to integrate google calendar API in the ionic angular for node js file

Tags: node.js, typescript

when I integrate google calendar API node js (to create events and create g meet) file into my angular application, and tried to run getting this below error

code: 403,
errors: [
{
domain: 'calendar',
reason: 'forbiddenForServiceAccounts',
message: 'Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.'
}
]

What is the possible solution for the below error?

message: 'Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.'